# Append data attributes onto a child DOM element, in a tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I've got a tag helper, `styled-checkbox`, that wraps a `<input type="checkbox">` and adds other elements so that I get a custom styled checkbox. The final rendered checkbox has this DOM structure:

```
<span>
  <input type="checkbox"...>
  <label..>
  <input type="hidden"..>
</span>
```

To do this, my TagHelper changes the TagName, and then appends the HTML:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "span";
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder("");
    content.Append($@"<input type=""checkbox"" value=""true"" name=""{Name}"" ... />");
    ... more content Appending here ...

    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content.ToString());
}
```

However, any data-attributes that I add to my tag when I use it, are appending to the `span`. I want them instead to be appended to the `input` element - is this possible?

E.g.:

```
<styled-checkbox data-foo="bar"></styled-checkbox>
```

In that example, I want the 'data-foo' attrribute to be appended to the checkbox input - but I can't see a way to do this, is is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[TagBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.tagbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2)** and handle attributes of an element.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("styled-checkbox")]  
    public class MyCustomTagHelper : TagHelper  
    {  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)  
        {  
            output.TagName = "span";  
            output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;  
            // collect all attributes of styled-checkbox tag
            var attributes = context.AllAttributes.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value.ToString()); 

            var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            CreateInputTagBuilder(attributes).WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            CreateHiddenInputTagBuilder().WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            // clear attributes of styled-checkbox
            output.Attributes.Clear();
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());
        }  
        private TagBuilder CreateInputTagBuilder(Dictionary<string,string> attributes)
        {

            var inputBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
            inputBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes);

            // use MergeAttribute instead of Add, Add method throws exception if an attribute exists
            inputBuilder.MergeAttribute("type","checkbox");
            inputBuilder.MergeAttribute("name",this.Name);

            return inputBuilder;
        }
        private TagBuilder CreateHiddenInputTagBuilder()
        {
            var inputBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
            inputBuilder.Attributes.Add("type","hidden");
            return inputBuilder;
        }
    }
```

cshtml:

```
<styled-checkbox data-foo="bar" value="33" name="saeed"></styled-checkbox>
```

output:

```
<span>
    <input data-foo="bar" name="saeed" type="checkbox" value="33">
    <input type="hidden">
</span>
```

Comment: Aha - I just needed the `var attributes = context.AllAttributes.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value.ToString());` - that was the missing piece, then I can add them to my input ;)